# new to python: for i in range with tabs + 2

Tags: python, tabs, range

I'm learning python and i want to know how to do this

```
 0
   2
     4
        6
          ...
            50
```

this is the start code but how to continue please help

```
for i in range (0, 50, 2):
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Please, your homework is meant for you to solve. You being new to python is not an excuse to not do it, because you will never learn that way.

Comment: thanks for to reply, it's not my homework man i just want to learn and i don't know how to do it, thats all.

Comment: It is a difficult road and you will struggle but that is the only way. Bang your head or don't do it at all.

Comment: It's still homework, you assigned to yourself instead of from a teacher.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Range creates a list [0, 2, 4, ..., 48]

This meaans the `i+=1` is superfluous.

Your next step is to add the spaces, which, conveniently, you are supposed to have the number of spaces as the number being printed (I think).

python conveniently has the ability to repeat a character with multiply, so the suggested code would be

```
for i in range(0, 52, 2):
    print(" "*i+str(i))
```